# How to avoid same API Calls multiple times on Angular 4.?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, api, web-services

It is seen that when I submit a form on Angular 4, it makes 2 calls for a single call. When I check the log it is came to know that it is hitted two times. How can I over come this.? When I submit all forms it inserted two times the same form data

[Component on project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EETYX.png)

[Service I have Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1hhR.png)

Comment: I assume you get one OPTIONS request and then the actual request. This is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Agree wit @Chrillewoodz. If it is not so, you should post a screenshot of the request and the code which produces it in order to find any possible issue.

Comment: It seems to be 2 requests for a single click

Comment: Show some code, for the form and the associated class, so we can help you better.

Comment: I have added the screenshots of my code please go through

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, how can I handle this OPTIONS request, as it is a mandatory method..Thanks in Advance

Comment: You don't. Try swapping `takeUntil` for `first()` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: It doesn't change anything..can I handle this in server side..?

Answer (score 1):

1. As  [Chrillewoodz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4054974/chrillewoodz) mentioned it can be OPTIONS request. This is pre-flight request made by some browsers as a safety measure to ensure that the request being done is trusted by the server. You can`t disable it.
2. If it is not an OPTIONS request make sure you don`t have "click" event on a 'submit' button and "ngSubmit" on a form itself. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by make a boolean variable `apiCalled` and if it is false don't call your api otherwise call it

```
@Injectable()
export default class myService {
    apiCalled: boolean = false;
    consturctor(private Http _http){

    }
    callApi() {
        if(apiCall)
            return;
        else {
            this.apiCall = true;
            this._http.get("write url").subscripe(
                res => {

                }, err => {
                }, ()=> {
                    this.apiCall = false;
                } 
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and once he finished calling the api you will be able to call that api again

Comment: It seems only one time invoked on the function but makes api call twice..so much confused

Comment: it shouldn't do that btw i edited my solution check it and add the complete method

Comment: Argument of type '(complete: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'. What may be the cause of the issue..?

Comment: that's happened because the complete function doesn't take any param i edited my solution you can check it

Comment: gotoSubmit(){
    return this.serviceAPI
           .callApi(this.model.selctedList,
            .subscribe(respo => {
           //alert("res");            
    }); 

  } What I change made to component part, here am using subscibe.?

Comment: i didn't understand what do you want

Comment: ohh okay replace your subscribe call with my subscribe and put your code inside the res function

Comment: I have added the screenshots of the file I have used